# how to decreasing the size of the font by click in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox

I working with windows form application.I am confused how to decrease a font in the richtextbox. I try with my best knowledge but can't do it. I have try with the function. one most important a current font size will be must save..my coding part ::-

```
  static int dmk;
    public void fun()
    {
        int dk = Convert.ToInt32(richTextBox1.Font.Size); // font save run time
        dmk = dk;
    }

    private void sizeDecreaseToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {   int ab = dmk;
        int ak = ab--;

       // .Font = new Font(textBox.Font.FontFamily, 16);

        richTextBox1.Font = new Font(richTextBox1.Font.FontFamily, ak);           
    }
```

I want to my font decreased one button click like that in Microsoft word. The data only run time enter.

I know my English very bad.  thanks in advanced...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this code and see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14241765/how-to-increase-and-decrease-text-size-on-a-textbox)

```
Font font = richTextBox1.Font;
float newSize = font.Size;
newSize -= 2.0F;
richTextBox1.Font = new Font(font.FontFamily, newSize, font.Style);
```